# Programa Feito em QT C++ crasha ao executar evento

Tags: css, banco-de-dados, c++, sqlite, qt

Estou criando um **programa em QT** com C++ para controle de Vendas, porém no Dialogo de Consultas estou com um problema.
Nele tenho um evento de clique de botão, onde ele deve abrir o banco de dados e atualizar informações, porém o programa crasha e não exibe nenhum erro, já tentei deixar só as atribuições de variável (tirando o banco de dados) mas ele crasha do mesmo jeito!!!

*consultas.h*

```
#ifndef CONSULTAS_H
#define CONSULTAS_H
#include "connection.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QString>
#include <QList>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class consultas;
}

class consultas : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit consultas(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~consultas();
    Connection con;
    QString asc_desc = "ASC";
    QString nome;
    QString tel;
    QString ende;
    QString mail;
    int cont = 0;
    int id;
    void insert_table(QTableWidget *tabela, QString query_text);
    void insert_lineedit(QString query_text, QList<QLineEdit*> items);

private slots:
    void on_central_currentChanged(int index);

    void on_radio_asc_clicked();

    void on_radio_desc_clicked();

    void on_tabela_itemSelectionChanged();

    void on_btn_save_clicked();

private:
    Ui::consultas *ui;
};

#endif // CONSULTAS_H
```

*consultas.cpp*

```
#include "consultas.h"
#include "ui_consultas.h"

consultas::consultas(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::consultas)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

consultas::~consultas()
{
    delete ui;
}

void consultas::insert_table(QTableWidget *tabela, QString query_text) {
    cont = 0;
    if (con.init()) {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare(query_text);
        if (query.exec()) {
            while (query.next()) {
               tabela->insertRow(cont);
               tabela->setItem(cont, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()));
               tabela->setItem(cont, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()));
               tabela->setItem(cont, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(2).toString()));
               tabela->setItem(cont, 3, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(3).toString()));
               tabela->setItem(cont, 4, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(4).toString()));
               tabela->setRowHeight(cont, 20);
               cont++;
            }
            con.exit();
        }
        else {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Erro ao Exibir Registros", "Erro ao Exibir Registros, Tente Novamente mais Tarde");
            con.exit();
        }
    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Erro ao Abrir Banco de Dados", "Erro ao Abrir Banco de Dados, Tente Novamente mais Tarde");
    }
}

void consultas::insert_lineedit(QString query_text, QList<QLineEdit*> items) {
    int query_cont = 1;
    if (con.init()) {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare(query_text);
        if (query.exec()) {
            query.first();
            while (query_cont < items.size()) {
                items[query_cont]->setText(query.value(query_cont).toString());
                query_cont++;
            }
            con.exit();
        }
        else {
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Erro ao Exibir Registros", "Erro ao Exibir Registros, Tente Novamente mais Tarde");
            con.exit();
        }
    }
    else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Erro ao Abrir Banco de Dados", "Erro ao Abrir Banco de Dados, Tente Novamente mais Tarde");
    }
}

void consultas::on_central_currentChanged(int index)
{
    if (index == 0) {
        ui->tabela->setRowCount(0);
        insert_table(ui->tabela, "SELECT * FROM tb_fornecedor ORDER BY id_fornec "+asc_desc);
        ui->tabela->horizontalHeader()->resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
        ui->tabela->verticalHeader()->resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
    }
}

void consultas::on_radio_asc_clicked()
{
    asc_desc = "ASC";
}

void consultas::on_radio_desc_clicked()
{
    asc_desc = "DESC";
}

void consultas::on_tabela_itemSelectionChanged()
{
    id = ui->tabela->item(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 0)->text().toInt();
    QList<QLineEdit*> lines = {ui->nome, ui->nome, ui->tel, ui->ende, ui->mail};
    insert_lineedit("SELECT * FROM tb_fornecedor WHERE id_fornec='"+QString::number(id)+"' ORDER BY id_fornec "+asc_desc, lines);
}

void consultas::on_btn_save_clicked()
{


    if (con.init()) {
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("UPDATE tb_fornecedor SET nome_fornec='"+nome+"', telefone_fornec='"+tel+"', endereco_fornec='"+ende+"', email_fornec='"+mail+"'"
                      "WHERE id_fornec='"+QString::number(id)+"'");
        if (query.exec()) {
            ui->tabela->setItem(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 1, new QTableWidgetItem(nome));
            ui->tabela->setItem(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 2, new QTableWidgetItem(tel));
            ui->tabela->setItem(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 3, new QTableWidgetItem(ende));
            ui->tabela->setItem(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 4, new QTableWidgetItem(mail));
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Informações Salvas com Sucesso", "Informações Foram Alteradas e Salvas com Sucesso");
        }
    }
}
```

*connection.h*

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H
#include <QtSql>
#include <QSqlQuery>

class Connection {
public:
    QSqlDatabase database;
    Connection() {
        database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    }
    void exit() {
        database.close();
    }
    bool init() {
        QString local = qApp->applicationDirPath();
        QString dataname = local + "/db/database.db";
        database.setDatabaseName(dataname);
        if (!database.open()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
};

#endif // CONNECTION_H
```

*erro*

```
13:51:32: The program has unexpectedly finished.
13:51:32: The process was ended forcefully.
13:51:32: /home/paulo/Área de trabalho/Qt-Projects/SistemaControleNotas/build-SistemaControleNotas-Desktop-Debug/SistemaControleNotas crashed.
```

Alguém sabe o por quê do programa crashar? desde já muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

o que está causando o crash da aplicação é o slot on_tabela_itemSelectionChanged,

```
id = ui->tabela->item(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 0)->text().toInt();
```

acontece que o método **currentRow()** retorna -1 em situações onde não há itens selecionados na tabela, e é justamente isso que irá ocorrer quando vc fizer a limpeza da tabela nesse trecho:

```
void consultas::on_central_currentChanged(int index){
if (index == 0) {
    ui->tabela->setRowCount(0);// <-
```

caso exista um item selecionado na tabela ao fazer a limpeza você irá disparar o signal QTableWidget::itemSelectionChanged().

o problema nesse caso é que a função ***QTableWidgetItem *QTableWidget::item(int row, int column) const***, retorna um ponteiro nulo caso não exista o índice informado.

> Returns the item for the given row and column if one has been set;
> otherwise returns nullptr.

em sequencia vc tentará acessar a função text() nesse ponteiro nulo.

uma alternativa para impedir isso seria:

```
void consultas::on_tabela_itemSelectionChanged()
{

    if( -1 != ui->tabela->currentRow())
    {
        QTableWidgetItem * item = ui->tabela->item(ui->tabela->currentRow(), 0);
        if(nullptr == item)
        {
            return;
        }
        bool conversao_ok = false;
        id = item->text().toInt(&conversao_ok);

        if(!conversao_ok)
        {
            return;
        }
        QList<QLineEdit*> lines = {ui->nome, ui->nome, ui->tel, ui->ende, ui->mail};
        insert_lineedit("SELECT * FROM tb_fornecedor WHERE id_fornec='"+QString::number(id)+"' ORDER BY id_fornec "+asc_desc, lines);
    }
}
```

Algumas outras recomendações, existe um erro no slot void consultas::on_btn_save_clicked(), ele irá sempre limpar os dados dos registros no banco, isso porque você está construindo o query utilizando os atributos

```
QString nome;
QString tel;
QString ende;
QString mail;
```

que não são alterado ao decorrer do seu código, na hora que você for fazer a alteração para que os valores sejam puxados dos inputs do usuário tome cuidado de validar os campos, pois vc corre o risco de deixar seu código vulnerável a SQLInjection, ou mesmo algo mais simples. se um usuário informar por exemplo o endereço "Rua Pedra D'Água" o seu query irá dar erro e não será feita a alteração.
outro exemplo seria se um usuário mal intencionado colocar o nome do fornecedor como

> fornecedor 2 ',id_fornec='123

poderendo assim alterar dados do seu banco que inicialmente você não iria permitir a alteração